# Text field clear automatically after entering the value as sendkeys

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to login on my mobile webbrowser. After passing my username as string, it clears automatically.

My code is

```
loginId.click(); 
loginId.sendKeys(userName);
```

The script fails only with the mobile browser. The login is a light box pop up.

I also tried javascript executor and actions. Nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share some more details. Like the DOM, code you tried and error screenshots if any.

Comment: loginId.click(); loginId.sendKeys(userName);

Comment: Script fails only with the mobile browser.The login is a light box pop up.

Comment: I tried javascript executor and actions.Nothing works...!

Comment: Plz, add all required details in the question.

Comment: I also encountered the same issue, Its entered the text in textbox but before clicking on submit button its cleared the entered text in text box. I tried the solution suggested by @viren tiwari but this one is also not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your application behavior. You can try with below code:

```
Actions action =new Actions(driver);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendkeys("textvalue");
action.sendkeys("Keys.TAB");
```